# Apache Beam Streaming unable to write to BigQuery column-based partition

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm currently building a streaming pipeline using Java SDK and trying to write to a BigQuery partitioned table using the BigQueryIO write/writeTableRows. I explored a couple of patterns but none of them succeed; few of them are below.

- Using SerializableFunction to determine TableDestination

```
.withSchema(TableSchemaFactory.buildLineageSchema())
.withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED) or CREATE_NEVER
.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)


and then calling this function inside the .to() method

    @Override
    public TableDestination apply(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> input) {

        TimePartitioning timePartitioning = new TimePartitioning();
        timePartitioning.setField("processingdate");
        String dest = String.format("%s.%s.%s", project, dataset, table);
        return new TableDestination(dest, null, timePartitioning);
```

I also tried to format the partition column obtained from input and add it as part of the String location with $ annotation, like below:

```
@Override
public TableDestination apply(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> input) {

        input.get("processingDate")
        ...convert to string MMddYYYY format
    
        TimePartitioning timePartitioning = new TimePartitioning();
        timePartitioning.setField("processingdate");
        String dest = String.format("%s.%s.%s$%s", project, dataset, table, convertedDate);
        return new TableDestination(dest, null, timePartitioning);
```

however, none of them succeed, either failing with

- invalid timestamp
- timestamp field value out of range
- You can only stream to partitions within 0 days in the past and 0 days in the future relative to the current date.
- The destination table's partition is not supported for streaming. You can only stream to meta-table of date partitioned tables.
- Streaming to metadata partition of column based partitioning table is disallowed.

I can't seem to get the right combination. Has anyone encountered the same issue before? Can anyone point me to the right direction or give me some pointers? what I want to achieve is load the streaming data based on the date column defined and not on processing time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect most of these issues will be solved if you drop the partition decorator from `dest`. In most cases the BigQuery APIs for loading data will  be able to figure out the right partition based on the messages themselves.

So try changing your definition of `dest` to:

```
String dest = String.format("%s.%s.%s", project, dataset, table);
```